# What do you expect a 2-sample t-test for the same two samples to return?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, python, scipy

I am using `scipy` in `Python` and the following return a `nan` value for whatever reason:

```
>>>stats.ttest_ind([1, 1], [1, 1])
Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)

>>>stats.ttest_ind([1, 1], [1, 1, 1])
Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan).
```

But whenever I use samples that have different summary statistics, I actually get a reasonable value:

```
stats.ttest_ind([1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2])
Ttest_indResult(statistic=-0.66666666666666663, pvalue=0.54146973927558495).
```

Is it reasonable to interpret a p-value of `nan` as `0` instead? Is there any reason from statistics that it doesn't make sense to run a 2-sample t-test on samples with the same summary statistics?

Comment: Assuming that the arguments of ttest_ind are lists of raw data, rather than summary statistics, then I'd assume the problem is due to the first two examples having no variance in either variable. This may potentially be a question best asked on Stack Overflow though

Comment: Yeah, I get a `nan` whenever I compare samples that have no variance. I was just wondering if it somehow makes no sense to do so from the point of view of statistics. I'll ask this question on StackOverflow, too.

Comment: No, it makes no sense. Statistical tests often effectively boil down to accounting for variance. You have no variance, so nothing to account for.

Comment: Okay, so I'll have to handle this special case in my larger program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with trying to compare two constant samples with a *t*-test is that the calculation of *t* involves an estimate of within-group SD in its denominator. From Wikipedia:

$$t = \frac{\bar {X}_1 - \bar{X}_2}{s_{X_1X_2} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}}$$

When both samples are constant, $s_{X_1X_2} = 0$, leading to a division by 0.

Comment: Is it correct to just say that the p-value in this case is 0?

Comment: No. $t$ is undefined, so you don't have a $p$-value for this test.

Comment: What about interpreting the p-value as the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis? Surely, I can say that two populations are the same if they have the same variance AND the same mean?

Comment: That's not what a $p$-value is; a $p$-value is the probability under the null hypothesis of getting a test statistic at least as extreme as the one you obtained.

Comment: Got it. I think I will leave the `nan` in my program then.